Raspberry Pi Copy Paste Chinese and it becomes "?"
I am using Raspberry Pi 4B and I used Raspberry Pi Connect and its function "Paste to Remote". When I am copy and past Chinese into Thonny, they all become

?

I also used Tiger VNC, found the same question.
For example, when I am trying to paste the following sentence to Thonny:

这是一个测试。

It becomes:
enter image description here
Please help. Thanks in advance.
I have tried to used
sudo apt install autocutsel
but it did not help
